# Why do we report standard deviation instead of standard deviation of the mean in cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, descriptive-statistics

I finished a statistics course and now I have some doubts about basic procedures used to train machine learning models.
For instance, k-fold crossvalidation results are usually reported as:

```
Mean +/- standard deviation
```

But why is that so? Isn't it more appropriate to use the standard deviation of the mean to represent the spread of accuracy scores between folds?

Comment: Standard deviation of mean = Standard error. Anyway, I am not familiar with such results. If anything, I would expect a SE.